# error in running a simple kivy program after uninstalling and installing python and pycharm error:raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')

Tags: python, kivy, mobile-application

```
from kivy.app import App


class mainWin():
    pass


class helpApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainWin()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    helpApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<mainWin>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        Label:
            text: "How can we help you???"
        Button:
            text: "Walking assistant"
        Button:
            text: "Text to Speech"
        Button:
            text: "Speech to Text"
```

Comment: the .kv file was indented properly but while pasting in here the indentation got messed up

Comment: mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(   ,   from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage   are also the errors

Answer (score 0):

The `build()` method of your `App` must return a `Widget` that will become the root of your `App`. But your `build()` method does not return a `Widget`. Perhap rplace:

```
class mainWin():
    pass
```

with:

```
class mainWin(Screen):
    pass
```